# calculating the intersection point of two lines with eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

Today I did my first steps in eigen and found the following solution to get the intersection point:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Calc intersection of line ac with bd:
    Vector2f a(8,2);
    Vector2f b(9,5);
    Vector2f c(6,6);
    Vector2f d(5,9);

    Matrix2f xx; 
    xx << c-a, b-d; 

    cout << "Here is the matrix xx:\n" << xx << endl;
    Vector2f x = xx.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b-a);
    Vector2f intersect1( a + x(0)* ( c-a ) );
    Vector2f intersect2( b + x(1)* ( d-b ) );

    cout << "intersect1\n" << intersect1 << std::endl;
    cout << "intersect2\n" << intersect2 << std::endl;
}
```

Q: Is there a function in eigen which give me directly the intersect result?
I believe I did to much handcrafted code here.

Comment: IMHO, I think this would be a better thing to ask on the code review site since it's working code

Comment: @NicoSchertler: If so, fine ;) Thanks! Make it an answer to earn some points;)

Comment: @NicoSchertler Even though it is not much code, there is much opportunity to implement things wrong (wrong signs, ignoring (near) singularities, ...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A line in two dimensions is the same as a [Hyperplane](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Hyperplane.html) in two-dimensions. And for that case there is an `intersection` method:

```
#include <Eigen/Geometry>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    using Line2 = Eigen::Hyperplane<float,2>;
    using Vec2  = Eigen::Vector2f;
    Vec2 a(8,2);
    Vec2 b(9,5);
    Vec2 c(6,6);
    Vec2 d(5,9);

    Line2 ac = Line2::Through(a,c);
    Line2 bd = Line2::Through(b,d);

    std::cout << "Intersection:\n" << ac.intersection(bd) << '\n';
}
```

Results in `[4, 10]`, as does your code.